# Compare date with present date in google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to compare the dates in ***Referral Date*** column with the present day and if ***Referral Date***  is lesser than present day then proceed with script if not throw an error "future date referral".

```
function dateFun() { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Worksheet");
var headers = ss.getRange('A:Z').getValues()[0];
var column =headers.indexOf("Referral Date")+1;
var presentDay = new Date();
  if (column.valueOf()>presentDay){
  }else{
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Future Date Referral")
 }
}
```

Image for reference

[image: referral column]

Hope its clear!

Answer (score 0):

Date objects can be compared with logical operators.

Ok you are on the right track here, but you are missing some important methods to get the data from the spreadsheet.

```js
function dateFun() {
  // Open the worksheet 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Worksheet");
  // Get data display values
  var range = ss.getRange('A:Z');
  // Get index of "Referral Date" in headers
  var headers = range.getValues()[0];
  var columnIndex = headers.indexOf("Referral Date")+1;
  // Get today's date
  var presentDay = new Date();
  // Loop through the dates column
  for(var i=1;i<=range.getNumRows();i++){
    // Get the value to compare to today 
    var rowDate = new Date(range.getValues()[i+1][columnIndex]);
    if(rowDate.valueOf()>presentDay.valueOf()){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Future Date Referral");
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Further reading:**

- [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [`getDisplayValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: I am beginner in scripts , i tried that but don't know whats wrong it gives popup irrespective of dates and i want script to stop running if date is greater than present date....i have put my code in question

Comment: I have one automation process this goes in between, I want to compare date under column **Referral Date** to the day present date(any day  i run script)  if the dates in column **Referral Date** are greater than present day then throw a popup if not run proceed with automation

Comment: I usually recommend commenting on the code, specially if you are a beginner. It helps to structure your program and break it down into simple steps.

Comment: Thanks for detailed code definitely i will comments from now... in the code you provided `values` is undefined in `for(var i=1;i<=values.getNumRows();i++)` i tried `for(var i=1;i<=headers.length;i++)` but i think again i am wrong, what should be `values`

Comment: it should be `range.getNumRows()` not values.

Comment: I tried that too i get `TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined` error

Comment: sorry but still getting same error... here is (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-Pq4pwOYENE_hPbQCGX7Rh07k-DP-AIX-IJdNj7v8U/edit?usp=sharing) i believe issue is here `var rowDate = new Date(range.getValues()[i+1][columnIndex]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213145/discussion-between-aerials-and-shiva).